# Async Call in $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to wait till the response comes from the `$http` request, in "angularjs"?
In `ajax`, a successful method is to set `async = false` like this,

```
jQuery.ajax({
     url: '/Something/Index',
     success: function (result) {
         result;
     },
     async: false
});
```

But Its not working in $http request in angularjs.Is there any method for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the promise returned by `$http` services in AngularJS and use `.then` function. This ensures that the first function response is received and then only code inside `.then` function would execute.

A sample code would be as below:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.factory('myService', function ($http) {
    return {            
        serverCall: function () {
            return $http.get('/Something/Index').then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            });
        }            
    };
});

app.controller("myController", function ($scope, myService) {

    $scope.GetDataFromServer = function () {

        // make the ajax call   
        var myData = myService.serverCall();

        // this executes after that ajax call is completed  
        myData.then(function (result) {                
            $scope.data = result;                
        });

    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get("url")
    .then(response => {
        // async success callback
    })
    .catch(err => { 
      // async error callback
    });
```

Comment: How to wait till the response comes from the $http request, in "angularjs"?This is my question?

Comment: then waits until response is back, this is called promise, you should know more about promises. Google js promise